shadcn-extension carousel shows this error while installing "Installing carousel...Error creating files: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory..."
I am trying to install a carousel with thumbnails from shadcn-extension. However, the installation fails when using the CLI command, and it shows the following error: Installing carousel...Error creating files: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\DEV\project\build-carousel\components\ui\extension\carousel.tsx'.
I am already using a carousel from Shadcn that works fine, but I need another carousel with thumbnails.
I am using Next.js 15 and have attached an image of my folder structure. If anyone could guide me on how to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks.
folder structur
